# Android: On text overflow, go to new line?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got the following Layout...

```
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/Pic" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="25dip" android:layout_height="25dip"></ImageView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:textColor="#5379E2" android:text="Item" android:id="@+id/Title"  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="" android:textColor="#000000" android:id="@+id/Description" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
        <TextView android:text="" android:textColor="#000000" android:id="@+id/url" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whenever the text gets too large for the single line it's on it overflows like so..

```
This is the first line and when it gets too big it does
                                                      t
                                                      h
                                                      i
                                                      s
```

But, what I'd like it to do is this..

```
This is the first line and when it gets too big it should
do this.
```

How would I achieve this?

**EDIT**

So It's appears this is happening because each of the three Textviews are taking up space like so..

```
 |------|-----|-----|
 |      |     |     |
 |______|_____|_____|
```

So, when it overflows it goes down to it's respective textline. The problem is this isn't what I want. I need the 3 textviews appears to compose of one sentence. I haven't just used one textview because I want to colour each textview differently.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this setting for your textview?

```
android:singleLine="false"
```

Comment: Yep, doesn't fix my problem. Also, that call is depreciated.